# How do I create an img image just big enough to hold one specific file?

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, mkfs, fat

I need to create an img disk image (using mkfs.fat) that will contain only one file.  I know I need to do this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1 count=SIZE
mkfs.fat disk.img
sudo mkdir /tmp/bla
sudo mount -o loop disk.img /tmp/bla
cp myfile /tmp/bla
sync
sudo umount /tmp/bla
sudo rmdir /tmp/bla
```

My question is, how do I determine SIZE so that the disk.img is just big enough to hold myfile?

Also, is there a way to avoid using sudo?

Comment: Why not just transport the file rather than an image containing the file?

Comment: ... or use trial and error. Your should need at least 700MB as a minimum; as per the actual size, your are not giving us enough data.